# SharePoint Designer: Error when connecting to my customer production server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Every time I try to connect to any SharePoint site running on my customer server I get the following error.

> An error occurred accessing your Microsoft SharePoint Foundation site
>   files. Authors - if authoring against a Web server, please contact the
>   Webmaster for this server's Web site. WebMasters - please see the
>   server's application event log for more details.

I already checked the sharepoint options in CA and in every site in the mentioned server. Everything seens correct but the error persists.

It looks like there is no direct relation to SharePoint and something else in the server but I was not able to determine what could cause such behaviour.

Hope someone here has something to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...  After a very long and painful headache we were able to find out what was causing this malfunction.

It was a .net agent from New Relic. This agent is used to analyse traffic, page load time and some other cool things. It basicly add some javascript to the head session of every response our IIS make and this code send some data to New Relic servers that will be processed to build some reports about the applications running in the IIS.

In the end, I just disabled it and SPD turned back to life.

Thanks.

PS: Boland was in the right path. I were able to find out the solution using Fiddler to analyse the responses from IIS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the event log. Do you see any error there? If not, it must be a network issue. Firewall is rare, because SPD works on TCP/80.

Comment: I have checked everything in Event Viewer logs and in the ULS. Nothing there. We are capable to navigate normaly through the sites and even add them as Network folder in the Windows File Explorer. I dont know where to look at.

Comment: If you checked that SPD is enabled, no logs in ULS, it must be something different. E.g. IIS is not handling the web service calls correctly, firewalls are blocking this, etc. It can be a lot of things depending on your environment. What about this one? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329362/en-us Otherwise look on Google, I see a lot of different causes.